# Node js performance testing statistics

Tags: node.js, load-testing

I already done testing with jmeter at my end it perform fine if i hit 1000 Request per second once only. But if i repeat same for continues 30 minute then the performance start degrading. so i want to know why it behave like this

Comment: Why don't you test it? I suspect the answer will be "just fine, thanks".

Comment: I already done testing with jmeter at my end it perform fine if i hit 1000 Request per second once only. But if i repeat same for continues 30 minute then the performance start degrading. so i want to know why it behave like this .Thanks in advance  @OrangeDog

Comment: If that's what you actually want to know then you should ask that question, not this one.

Answer (score 0):

In node each process is single threaded by design, therefore to get multiple threads, you have to have multiple processes. To take advantage of multi-core systems you want to launch a cluster of Node.js processes to handle the load.

One of ways to do that:
https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html - clustering
https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html - child processes

Or simply run multiple t2.nano instances of same process - here you can achieve auto scaling but it's not that simple.

One of realtime statistics:
1 core server cluster t2.small aws instance:
[image]

Real time 2 core server t2.medium aws instance:
[image]

At the end you will end up benchmarking, utilizing, tuning mysql database itself.

To answer question, scaling of node is pretty simple and it gives you awesome results.